# Install FedEx module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, fedex

I'm running Magento `2.4.1` and I am missing the `magento/module-fedex` module. However it is on github : https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4.1/app/code/Magento/Fedex .
By running a `composer require magento/module-fedex`, it will still not get it . Do you know why ?

I also see it in the docs: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/fedex.html . But i don't have those configurations.

Thanks

Comment: do you maybe have a replace somewhere in your composer.json or another module that replaces this?

Comment: @PhilippSander yes, I do a have this: `"replace": { "magento/module-fedex": "*", ...`, in my composer.json file

Comment: that's why you don't get it

Comment: true, thanks @PhilippSander